# Which database to select?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

I have used many databases like MySql,SqlServer2008,Oracle and Access in my projects but am confused which is efficient,scalable,less memory hungry and better speed across different platforms and environments.?

regards

Comment: Ok boss  i got it otherwise i was thinking why i got negative vote since i myself have developed many applications related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the comparison of all database:

[Comparison_of_database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools)

Now its depend on your requirement that which is good fit for you to use.